# Mount point to access the site's assets

Tags: sharepoint-online, webdav

I'm developing a Sharepoint Online website, and I'd like to use git's versioning on my CSS/JS/HTML assets.

The ideal solution for me would be to have a mount point pointing to my Sharepoint assets, so that I could even edit them from any computer (without having to use Sharepoint Designer).

And even more ideally, the solution would work on non-Windows system. There seem to be some webdav support in Sharepoint, at least to access Sharepoint's folders and files, but I'm not sure about access to the HTML/CSS of the Sharepoint site itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just put the assets in a library with versioning enabled along with check out and approval. This gives you version control and the ability to publish changes and see how they look before approving them. Once approved, they are then visible to the rest of the user base.

My experience with WebDAV in SharePoint is abysmal. It is too slow and too chatty to be a worth while tool.

Comment: It's a good lead and I'm going to use it as a last resort. WebDAV in sharepoint does seem a bit shady (no implementation of WebDAV have worked consistently so far: either not at all for most clients, and only sometimes with Windows' own client)... but if we could mount these files, we would have the ability to run script on them, which is optimal for us: most of our validation is an automated process, scripts waiting for new commits in a git repository and validating them. Without that, and the ability to easily run two different versions of a site at the same time, we'll lose a lot of time.